# Singular and regular points of a curve

Tags: calculus

Let C be the curve defined by equation $(x^2+y^2)^2= 4(x^2-y^2)$ ... I have found the singular points where the gradient vanishes and the points are $(0,0)$ and $( \pm \sqrt2 ,0)$ . Now i have to find the regular points the points where the tangents of C are horizontal or vertical . I need some hints . The hint I was given is that at regular points the gradient is always orthogonal to the tangent. But i don't understand what does it really mean ? .how could rewriting the curve in polar coordinates helps us in sketching the curve ?

Answer (score 1):

I must confess that I do not know how to use the hint you are given.

Considering the implicit function $$F=(x^2+y^2)^2- 4(x^2-y^2)=0$$ you already found that $$F'_x=4 x \left(x^2+y^2-2\right)$$ $$F'_y=4 y \left(x^2+y^2+2\right)$$ Now, using the implicit function theorem $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}=-\frac{x \left(x^2+y^2-2\right)}{y \left(x^2+y^2+2\right)}$$ So, now, you have to search the conditions which make $\frac{dy}{dx}$ equal to $0$ or undefined.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Yeah thanks i myself got nothing from the hint . What about sketching this curve after rewriting in polar coordinates i found it to be r^2=4cos2a

Comment: @Mathslovershah. It is a good idea, for sure.